# Approval of iOS app with mobile number registration

Tags: ios, review

Does Apple Review process approves an app which functions only after registration with user mobile number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you need to provide a demo account information, I think. Otherwise they won't be able to login during the review.